# Do I Need New Kitchen Faucet Handles?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I just replaced faucet washers and after reassembly, the tap doesn't work. There is a crack in the handle. Is a replacement handle needed?

Comment: It depends on what's broken. The "tap doesn't work" description is pretty generic.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you can get a new handle and if there are set screws that hold the handle on.

If you want to fix it and not replace the whole unit, do research on the parts you need.  If you can't get them you will need to replace the whole unit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you remove the tap again and check that you haven't jammed the jumper valve (washer) under the spindle preventing it from rising and letting water though to your spout.